# Loading times after large document slow with QWebView - PyQt

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt4, qwebview

My program uses a tabbed interface with QWebViews. Some HTML documents that I load into the QWebView are very large (textbook size). Other times, documents are small pamphlets.

Whenever I load a gigantic document first, all other subsequent loads are much slower, regardless of how big that document is. While a pamphlet will take a couple milliseconds to load normally, if it is loaded after one of these giant documents, it can take almost 10 seconds.

I've connected signals to the `loadProgress()` signal to each of my QWebViews. I can confirm that the slowdown is coming directory after I call `setHtml()`.

I've also cleared the caches before calling `setHtml()` using the following:

```
QWebSettings.clearIconDatabase()
QWebSettings.clearMemoryCaches()
```

At application startup, I set the following properties:

```
QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)
QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls, True)
QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.LocalStorageEnabled, True)
QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.AutoLoadImages, True)
QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavascriptCanAccessClipboard, True)
```

I'm at a loss on what to try next.

Pointers on what I should do next are much appreciated. Thanks!

P.S: I use MathJax SVG output and other JavaScript. So, the documents are very JavaScript heavy.

---

**Update**

Added the following to startup, with no effect:

```
QWebSettings.setObjectCacheCapacities(0, 0, 0)
```

This also didn't work:

```
QWebSettings.setMaximumPagesInCache(1)
```